# Spherical Impostors in three.js

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I'm working to port a native OpenGL application to WebGL by using the three.js framework. I'm stumbling on the implementation of spherical impostors.

Spherical Impostors are basically quads (or two triangles) that are rendered in a way that they always face the camera (much alike billboards).

By employing custom vertex and fragment shaders, for every point on the rendered quad, a new position and normal are generated in a way that emulates a sphere. For a more detailed description you can check out the following link: [link broken]

What is a possible strategy to port this feature in Three.js?

Comment: Maybe https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/codevember-2016/13/?

Comment: Any way you can update your link @pygabriel ? I clicked on it, and the new site tried to automatically install some unknown piece of software on my browser.

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks for letting me know, Link is probably dead :(

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.Sprite` are spherical impostors.
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_sprites

Edit: I clearly didn't have a proper understanding of what spherical impostors are. Please, disregard this answer. We haven't implemented those yet.

Comment: Is it possible to generate the correct gl_FragDepth for the spheres using a custom shader? I need to obtain a result like this: http://chemlab.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/norb_step1.png

Comment: Oh wait, I guess I didn't know what spherical impostors were... Pretty cool! We don't have that yet!