# Implementing imposters in three.js

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to do imposters in three.js - or is that not going to help with performance at all for a scene with >10,000 objects most of them being the same model?

Answer (score 2):

If you have thousands of the same object (with variations of position/size/rotation and perhaps color) then your first priority should be to make sure you don't have thousands of GPU draw call. A couple options:

(a) **static batching** — apply the objects' positions to their geometries (`geometry.applyMatrix( mesh.matrixWorld )`) then merge them with `THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries()`). The result can be drawn as a single large mesh. This takes up more memory, but is easier to set up.

(b) **gpu instancing** — more memory-efficient, but harder to do. See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html or https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh.

Once you've reduced the number of draw calls, profile the application again. If performance is still poor, you can reduce the total vertex count with impostors (or, really, just simpler meshes...). threejs does not generate impostors for you, per [Spherical Impostors in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152053/spherical-impostors-in-three-js).

Comment: Re: (b) Might also be worth looking at:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-instanced-mesh

Comment: Thanks, added this link to the answer. :)

Comment: Tried to follow the example you linked, but not sure why it's not working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861208/three-js-gpu-instantiation-with-custom-mesh-and-material