# three.js GPU Instantiation with custom mesh and material

Tags: three.js

Trying to implement GPU instantiation, following the [instances/gpu three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_instances_gpu).

However, somehow nothing seems to be loading in my attempt: http://designs.playgami.com/webgl_loader_fbx3.html

(here is the non-gpu instantiation version - http://designs.playgami.com/webgl_loader_fbx2.1.html)

Here's specifically where I am trying to load the fbx model just once, and then instantiate. I'm trying to instantiate using `var object = new THREE.Mesh( geo );`, but somehow that does not work?

```js
  function CreateCraneScape(texturearray,squareside,armyside){
                var total = texturearray.length;
                var halfside = Math.floor(squareside*0.5);

                loader.load( '/11272018-crane.fbx', function ( geo ) {
                    var k = 0;
                    // create cranes
                    for(var i=-halfside;i<=halfside;i++){
                        for(var j=-halfside;j<=halfside;j++){
                            var object = new THREE.Mesh( geo );
                            CraneApplyTexture(object,texturearray[k]); 
                            CranePosRot(object,i,j);
                            k++;
                        }   
                    }

                    // create army
                    
                    for(var i=-(halfside+armyside);i<=(halfside+armyside);i++){ 
                            for(var j=-(halfside+armyside);j<=(halfside+armyside);j++){ 
                                if(j<-halfside||j>halfside || (i<-halfside||i>halfside)){ 
                                    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geo );
                                    CraneApplyTexture(object,''); 
                                    CreatePosRot(object,i,j);
                                }
                            }   
                    }

                });
   }
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide an editable example? jsfiddle, codepen, code snippets etc.

Comment: not sure if i've set this jsfiddle up correctly, basically just copy/pasted with full links instead of relative linnks - https://jsfiddle.net/yosun/qtsv59x3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently FBXLoader does not load just the mesh geometry but actually the entire three.js game object. So, the mesh instantiation needed to reference the geometry of the first child.

`geo = geo.children[0].geometry;`